# CSS float right not working correctly

Tags: html, css, css-float

My right float is not working how i expect it to.

I want my button nicely aligned to the right of my text above a line :

```
<div style="padding: 5px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: gray; border-bottom-style: solid;">

    My Text

<button type="button" class="edit_button" style="float: right; margin:5px;">My Button</button>

</div>
```

However it always seems to hover over the line.

If I increase the padding or margin of the DIV then the button on the right still seems to be pushed over the line at the bottom.

I have tried to play around with paddings and margins of the button on the right, but i can't seem to get it to be placed neatly next to the text.

Fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/qvsy7/

Many thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you need to wrap your text inside div and float it left while wrapper div should have height, and I've also added line height for vertical alignment

```
<div style="border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: gray;height:30px;">
   <div style="float:left;line-height:30px;">Contact Details</div>

    <button type="button" class="edit_button" style="float: right;">My Button</button>

</div>
```

also js fiddle here =)
http://jsfiddle.net/xQgSm/

Comment: This doesn't really work - see how the button doesn't vertically align when you increase the size of the container: http://jsfiddle.net/jpdbos8u/

Answer (score 14):

Here is one way of doing it.

If you HTML looks like this:

```
<div>Contact Details
    <button type="button" class="edit_button">My Button</button>
</div>
```

apply the following CSS:

```css
div {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: gray;
    overflow: auto;
}
.edit_button {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0; /* for demo only */
}
```

The trick is to apply `overflow: auto` to the `div`, which starts a new block formatting context.  The result is that the floated button is enclosed within the block area defined by the `div` tag.

You can then add margins to the button if needed to adjust your styling.

In the original HTML and CSS, the floated button was out of the content flow so the border of the `div` would be positioned with respect to the in-flow text, which does not include any floated elements.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/AGavv/

Answer (score 9):

Verry Easy, change order of element:

Origin

```
<div style="">

    My Text

    <button type="button" style="float: right; margin:5px;">
       My Button
    </button>

</div>
```

Change to:

```
<div style=""> 

    <button type="button" style="float: right; margin:5px;">
       My Button
     </button>

   My Text

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

LIke this

**[final answer](http://jsfiddle.net/qvsy7/9/)**

**css**

```
h2 {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.edit_button {
    float: right;
}
```

---

**[demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/qvsy7/8/)**

**css**

```
h2 {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: gray;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.edit_button {
    float: right;
}
```

**html**

```
<h2>
Contact Details</h2>
<button type="button" class="edit_button" >My Button</button>
```

---

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qvsy7/2/)**

**html**

```
<div style="border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: gray; float:left;">
Contact Details



</div>
<button type="button" class="edit_button" style="float: right;">My Button</button>
```

Comment: the line has to go under all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You have not used `float:left` command for your text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your text in an element eg: for paragraph in **P** tag also you can use **div** tag.
Here is your same code in **p** tag

```
<div style="border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: gray;">
```

Contact Details Contact DetailsContact Details Contact Details

My Button

```html
<div style="border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: gray;">
<p>
Contact Details Contact DetailsContact Details Contact Details
</p>
<button type="button" class="edit_button" style="float: right;">My Button</button>

</div>
```