# Not able to float ListItem right in List

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have an array containing object which needs to be displayed in ListItem of List. Now i want to display these ListItems from array Objects in 'left' - 'right'. Odd number needs to go in left and Even in right but `float:right` is not working. Here is my [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-cvt4f?file=/demo.js) link.

```
list: {
marginTop: "8%",
float: "right",
marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
}
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS float right not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092014/css-float-right-not-working-correctly)

Comment: @SibasishMohanty No

Comment: I'm sorry the question is not clear to me. Are you trying to render your list items in to two columns?

Comment: @Lara, Do you mean like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-lb6up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this css code for reverse your div. If the div displaying as a flex

```
flex-direction: row-reverse
```

if not displaying as a flex

```
display:flex
flex-direction: row-reverse
```

check the example below

```css
.block {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.without-reverse {
  display: flex;
}

.with-reverse {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="without-reverse">
  <div class="block">A</div>
  <div class="block">B</div>
  <div class="block">C</div>
</div>
<div class="with-reverse">
  <div class="block">A</div>
  <div class="block">B</div>
  <div class="block">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide an example to make it a valid answer, and for future visitors to better understand it