# float:left not working for me in HTML CSS

Tags: html, html-table, css-float

I have developed a script to present an active YouTube chat along with a summary of who's in the chat.  The idea is that the table of chat items will appear to the right of the list of chat members.  However, in latest versions of Safari and in Chrome, the float seems not to be working, and the tables are presented one-above-another.  Here's a sample extract of the generated HTML which has the problem.

```css
body {
  background-image: '/bg-standard.jpg';
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.twoTables {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

.tableLeft {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.tableRight {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.twoTables::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

headingLink {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dummyRow {
  line-height: 1px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.freeze-table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
}

thead th {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 20;
  min-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

xth,
xtd {
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: none;
  outline-offset: -1px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 0 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 100%;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

tr {
  min-height: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #ffffff
}

pageElement {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center
}

a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.fit {
  /* set relative picture size */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.imgbox {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
}

.center-fit {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .tableLeft {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tableRight {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method='POST' action=/ YouTube/latestChats.php>
  <table style='border-collapse:collapse;'>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='highlightMsg' id='highlightMsg' checked>
        <label for='highlightMsg'>Highlight messages</label></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='msgUseRegEx' id='msgUseRegEx'>
        <label for='msgUseRegEx'>Use REGEX</label></td>
      <td>Message filter</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='msg' value='request' size=30></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='invertOrder' id='invertOrder' checked>
        <label for='invertOrder'>Latest first</label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='radio' name='emoteMgmt' value='text'>&nbsp;Emoticons&nbsp;as&nbsp;text&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='radio' name='emoteMgmt' checked value='icon'>&nbsp;Emoticons&nbsp;as&nbsp;image&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='radio' name='emoteMgmt' value='strip'>&nbsp;Strip&nbsp;emoticons&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type='submit' name='backToYouTubeStuff' value='Go Back'>
  <br>
</form>
<br>
<div class='twoTables'>
  <div id='watchers' class='tableLeft'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Watcher</th>
        <th>*</th>
        <th>Joined</th>
        <th>Latest</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>request</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>07:47</td>
        <td>1805.0m</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Joe Something - guru</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>07:44</td>
        <td>1805.2m</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>(<span style="font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">Tony</span>) Tropic</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>06:48</td>
        <td>1839.9m</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id='chats' class='tableRight'>
    <table style='border-collapse:collapse;border:0px solid white;'>
      <tr style='color:white; border:0px;'>
        <td colspan=3 style='text-align:center;background-color:darkblue;color:white;font-size:115%;font-weight:bold;border:solid white;'>2023-08-27</td>
        <td colspan=2 style='background-color:darkblue;color:white;font-size:115%;font-weight:bold;border:solid white;'><a href='https://youtu.be/ForShow'>2023-08-27 Livestream Title (23-074)</a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>1</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:47</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:51)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>Tropic</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3531' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               Ty dad</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>2</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:47</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:41)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>Joe Something</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3521' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               c ya guys</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>3</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:47</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:37)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>request</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3517' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               Sold it Brad</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>5</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:46</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:28)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>Silent Chatter</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3508' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               HAPPY Bday Son</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>6</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:46</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:27)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>request</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3507' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               good job george</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>7</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:46</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:23)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>Danny Incognito</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3503' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               bye bye guys</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan=5 style='background-color: #666 ;color: #fff ;z-index: 20 ;min-height: 30px ;height: 30px ;text-align: left ;'>End of data. </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have searched for solutions to similar problems, but none of them seem to exactly match my issue, save [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092014/css-float-right-not-working-correctly).  For this one, I have two problems with the accepted answer ("you need to wrap your text inside div and float it left while wrapper div should have height... ): (1) My code is already wrapped by and specifying float; and (2) I haven't seen evidence that I must specify a height. I think this is yet another variation of the problem. Then there's the pesky comment that the accepted answer doesn't work.

Am I doing something obviously wrong here with regards to making float work?  I don't see anything.

NOTE: There are a lot of style attributes defined but not used here.  The actual finished product is capable of much more than just this pair of tables.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove the 50% width on the table containers, or set the box-sizing to border-box. The tables will float as-is, but by setting the width as-is they're too wide and wrap.

**Example 1**

```css
body {
  background-image: '/bg-standard.jpg';
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.twoTables {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

.tableLeft {
  float: left;
  xwidth: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.tableRight {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.twoTables::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

headingLink {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dummyRow {
  line-height: 1px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.freeze-table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
}

thead th {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 20;
  min-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

xth,
xtd {
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: none;
  outline-offset: -1px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 0 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 100%;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

tr {
  min-height: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #ffffff
}

pageElement {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center
}

a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.fit {
  /* set relative picture size */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.imgbox {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
}

.center-fit {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .tableLeft {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tableRight {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method='POST' action=/ YouTube/latestChats.php>
  <table style='border-collapse:collapse;'>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='highlightMsg' id='highlightMsg' checked>
        <label for='highlightMsg'>Highlight messages</label></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='msgUseRegEx' id='msgUseRegEx'>
        <label for='msgUseRegEx'>Use REGEX</label></td>
      <td>Message filter</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='msg' value='request' size=30></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='invertOrder' id='invertOrder' checked>
        <label for='invertOrder'>Latest first</label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='radio' name='emoteMgmt' value='text'>&nbsp;Emoticons&nbsp;as&nbsp;text&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='radio' name='emoteMgmt' checked value='icon'>&nbsp;Emoticons&nbsp;as&nbsp;image&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='radio' name='emoteMgmt' value='strip'>&nbsp;Strip&nbsp;emoticons&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type='submit' name='backToYouTubeStuff' value='Go Back'>
  <br>
</form>
<br>
<div class='twoTables'>
  <div id='watchers' class='tableLeft'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Watcher</th>
        <th>*</th>
        <th>Joined</th>
        <th>Latest</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>request</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>07:47</td>
        <td>1805.0m</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Joe Something - guru</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>07:44</td>
        <td>1805.2m</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>(<span style="font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">Tony</span>) Tropic</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>06:48</td>
        <td>1839.9m</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id='chats' class='tableRight'>
    <table style='border-collapse:collapse;border:0px solid white;'>
      <tr style='color:white; border:0px;'>
        <td colspan=3 style='text-align:center;background-color:darkblue;color:white;font-size:115%;font-weight:bold;border:solid white;'>2023-08-27</td>
        <td colspan=2 style='background-color:darkblue;color:white;font-size:115%;font-weight:bold;border:solid white;'><a href='https://youtu.be/ForShow'>2023-08-27 Livestream Title (23-074)</a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>1</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:47</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:51)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>Tropic</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3531' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               Ty dad</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>2</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:47</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:41)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>Joe Something</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3521' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               c ya guys</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>3</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:47</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:37)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>request</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3517' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               Sold it Brad</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>5</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:46</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:28)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>Silent Chatter</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3508' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               HAPPY Bday Son</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>6</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:46</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:27)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>request</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3507' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               good job george</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>7</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:46</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:23)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>Danny Incognito</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3503' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               bye bye guys</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan=5 style='background-color: #666 ;color: #fff ;z-index: 20 ;min-height: 30px ;height: 30px ;text-align: left ;'>End of data. </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example 2**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: '/bg-standard.jpg';
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.twoTables {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

.tableLeft {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.tableRight {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.twoTables::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

headingLink {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dummyRow {
  line-height: 1px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.freeze-table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
}

thead th {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 20;
  min-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

xth,
xtd {
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: none;
  outline-offset: -1px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 0 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 100%;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

tr {
  min-height: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #ffffff
}

pageElement {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center
}

a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.fit {
  /* set relative picture size */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.imgbox {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
}

.center-fit {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .tableLeft {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tableRight {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method='POST' action=/ YouTube/latestChats.php>
  <table style='border-collapse:collapse;'>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='highlightMsg' id='highlightMsg' checked>
        <label for='highlightMsg'>Highlight messages</label></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='msgUseRegEx' id='msgUseRegEx'>
        <label for='msgUseRegEx'>Use REGEX</label></td>
      <td>Message filter</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='msg' value='request' size=30></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='invertOrder' id='invertOrder' checked>
        <label for='invertOrder'>Latest first</label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='radio' name='emoteMgmt' value='text'>&nbsp;Emoticons&nbsp;as&nbsp;text&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='radio' name='emoteMgmt' checked value='icon'>&nbsp;Emoticons&nbsp;as&nbsp;image&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='radio' name='emoteMgmt' value='strip'>&nbsp;Strip&nbsp;emoticons&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type='submit' name='backToYouTubeStuff' value='Go Back'>
  <br>
</form>
<br>
<div class='twoTables'>
  <div id='watchers' class='tableLeft'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Watcher</th>
        <th>*</th>
        <th>Joined</th>
        <th>Latest</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>request</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>07:47</td>
        <td>1805.0m</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Joe Something - guru</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>07:44</td>
        <td>1805.2m</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>(<span style="font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">Tony</span>) Tropic</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>06:48</td>
        <td>1839.9m</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id='chats' class='tableRight'>
    <table style='border-collapse:collapse;border:0px solid white;'>
      <tr style='color:white; border:0px;'>
        <td colspan=3 style='text-align:center;background-color:darkblue;color:white;font-size:115%;font-weight:bold;border:solid white;'>2023-08-27</td>
        <td colspan=2 style='background-color:darkblue;color:white;font-size:115%;font-weight:bold;border:solid white;'><a href='https://youtu.be/ForShow'>2023-08-27 Livestream Title (23-074)</a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>1</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:47</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:51)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>Tropic</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3531' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               Ty dad</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>2</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:47</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:41)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>Joe Something</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3521' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               c ya guys</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>3</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:47</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:37)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>request</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3517' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               Sold it Brad</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>5</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:46</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:28)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>Silent Chatter</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3508' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               HAPPY Bday Son</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>6</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:46</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:27)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>request</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3507' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               good job george</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>7</td>
        <td style='text-align:center;color:Blue;'>07:46</td>
        <td style='text-align:right;color:Blue;'>(58:23)</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>Danny Incognito</td>
        <td style='text-align:left;color:Blue;'>
          <a style='color:blue;text-decoration:none;' href='https://youtu.be/ForShow?t=3503' target='_blank'>_&nbsp;
               bye bye guys</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan=5 style='background-color: #666 ;color: #fff ;z-index: 20 ;min-height: 30px ;height: 30px ;text-align: left ;'>End of data. </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very good.  Solved my problem.  Ive gone with removing the 50% widths.  I'm still struggling with knowing when HTML will scale and when it will not.  Neaest I can determine, there's no absolute sizing  in my code, and yet things can overflow.  Weird to me.  It matters, because the next thing I nedd to do, is to put a box around that table on the right, and scroll it.  (The one on the left is not expected to grow beyond 20 ines.)  Anyway, that's all moot.  Thanks for a great and easy solution!